# Error installing cordova plugin from github url (meteor 1.2)

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I have a meteor app that uses several cordova plugins that are installed from github (because they are not on the registry). The app was working fine under 1.1.0.3 but in meteor 1.2 I get an error when I try to run the app.

Following the updated [instructions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-integration#using-cordova-plugins-directly-in-your-application), I tried removing and re-adding the plugin like this:

```
meteor add cordova:com.cordova.plugins.sms@https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin.git#17c4da078f6c0d9f762ac10f5015440ee1c81d07
```

The referenced commit exists, but when I then run `meteor run android-device` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /var/folders/5x/mffg5c9j3_1c6cbst5p82tkr0000gn/T/npm-2296-a0ad1527/git-cache-f63007629e41/03fe48b62411cbff22229ca13cc3ac8b282f7945
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /var/folders/5x/mffg5c9j3_1c6cbst5p82tkr0000gn/T/npm-2296-a0ad1527/git-cache-739cb14fc690/03fe48b62411cbff22229ca13cc3ac8b282f7945
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:                                              

   While adding plugin com.verso.cordova.clipboard@https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin com.verso.cordova.clipboard@https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git via
   registry.
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
   Error: EISDIR, read
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try
   running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)

ExitWithCode:1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's [a known bug](https://forums.meteor.com/t/error-adding-cordova-plugin-from-git-repo/10135/4) in the current version (1.2.0.1) and a workaround is to use the old format in `.meteor/cordova-plugins`:

```
com.cordova.plugins.sms@https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/tarball/17c4da078f6c0d9f762ac10f5015440ee1c81d07
```